# Change HSQL database in Java EE web project

Tags: jakarta-ee, hsqldb

I have two projects: one for JPA persistence and other for the Java EE Web project which uses the ZK framework.

For the database I am using HSQL with the persistence-unit defined as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="rubioseq-database" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>sing.proyectosi.Employee</class>
    <class>sing.proyectosi.Department</class>
    <class>sing.proyectosi.Project</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/store" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Well, and the web project uses this persistence unit. My issue is the following: the HSQL files are stored under my home directory (/home/user/data/store) and I wonder if there is any way of specifying a route relative to the project path.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the database is defined below. You need to change it to include a variable that equals a directory path defined in your JEE web:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:${mydbpath}/store" />
```

See the Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this.